# differencing op amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, differential

How would I implement an differencing op amp circuit that performs the operation 5*v1-2*v2 with the op amp power supply being 12vdc? I already tried the basic circuit but I got negative resistance. Is that normal?

Schematic:
[image: http://imgur.com/xtxVYI3]

Comment: Why don't you post the schematic of what you tried? I have no idea what you mean when you say you got negative resistance.

Comment: @Matt: When he calculated `R3`, he apparently got a negative value.

Comment: So I see... So what he's trying to get is a difference amplifier that runs off a 12V single supply. What is shown here will not come anywhere close to that. Answer enroute...

Comment: I still got a negative value for R3 for some reason

Comment: Is this single supply, or split?

Comment: split, has -vcc and +vcc

Answer (score 3):

What you have now is an analog comparator due to positive feedback.  Diagram your circuit again, this time using negative feedback, and when you repeat the calculations you'll get much more reasonable resistor values.

(If you're copying from a textbook sum/difference amp circuit, please note that having the feedback resistor top or bottom is not important, connecting it to the inverting input pin is, and that op-amp symbols vary in placement of the input pins.  Your textbook likely drew the circuit with pin 2 above pin 3.)

Of course, with a 12V supply, your inputs will have to be chosen so that the output isn't 40V.

You might try a topology like this (resistor values are not set correctly, that's up to you):

[image: CircuitLab Schematic 7ducur]

(And for Matt's benefit, here's the solution, showing that R3 is not unnecessarily adding complication)

[image: CircuitLab Schematic f7qaq8]

A nice way to analyze this is to first consider the circuit with only \$R1\$ and \$R2\$ present.  Then

$$V_{out} = (1 + \frac{R1}{R2}) V3 - \frac{R1}{R2} V4$$

If the non-inverting gain is too high, use a voltage divider on \$V3\$.  (This gives the Wikipedia circuit).

If the inverting gain is too high, use a voltage divider on \$V4\$.

Final gains:

$$G = \frac{R1}{R2 || R3} = \frac{R1 R2 R3}{R2 + R3}$$
$$V_{out} = (G+1) \frac{R5}{R5 + R6} V3 - G \frac{R3}{R2 + R3} V4$$

Comment: I'm new at this but I used the text book formula to find the resistance values, when I solved for R3, I got the negative value.

Comment: @user1047968: First, fix your schematic.  Then, apply the ideal op-amp rules (input current is zero, input voltages are equal) and solve Kirchoff's Current and Voltage Laws.  You get to pick one or two of the resistor values, for example, R4 as 1k.

Comment: It's not that simple with a single supply.

Comment: @Matt: Neither the question nor the circuit indicate single supply.

Comment: The question states "with the op amp power supply being 12vdc," he needs to clarify this point. The schematic indicates nothing useful to me other than a fundamental lack of understanding.

Comment: why can't it be like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Op-Amp_Differential_Amplifier.svg, as far as I can see, all I need is the resistors with the appropriate value to carry out the operation.

Comment: Your schematic is wrong. The one from Wikipedia is correct.

Comment: @user1047968: That wikipedia diagram is really close to mine (make my `R3` infinite).

Comment: @MattYoung: The one from wikipedia is a special case of mine, with `R3 = infinity`.

Comment: That is going to change the the \$\dfrac{R_f}{R_i}\$ term to something more complicated needlessly.

Comment: which resistor value should I set first ideally so that I can solve for the rest of them?

Comment: @user1047968: Perhaps `R1` and `R6` (in my schematic).

Comment: @Matt: The wikipedia circuit doesn't allow arbitrary gain, does it?  Specifically, the non-inverting gain is at most 1 more than the inverting gain.  I'm not sure my topology fixes that, but I do know the wikipedia one won't work.

Comment: The Wikipedia circuit does work, I've used it to implement a zero and span circuit multiple times. The output equation is \$V_{out}=\dfrac{R_f}{R_i}(V_{ni}-V_{inv})\$ when \$R_f=R_1=R_6\$ and \$R_i=R_2=R_5\$, in terms of your schematic. These components being equal is essential to its operation. The biggest problem is the fact that the input impedance of the inverting side does not remain fixed because of the negative feedback. I haven't done the analysis but I don't think your topology can fix that, and the only way around it is to upgrade to an instrumentation amplifier or add a buffer.

Comment: @Matt: This question requires that those gains NOT be equal.  I didn't say that Wikipedia is wrong, or that the circuit shown there doesn't work as described.  But it is not a solution to this question (not with positive resistor values, anyway).

Comment: @BenVoigt, actually this clears up a lot of things for me, so are you saying that I need to have the R3 in your schematic for my problem?

Comment: @user1047968: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Is there a specific name for your circuit?

Comment: It's just the general case of the summing/differencing amplifier.  If non-inverting gain < inverting gain + 1, use the wikipedia circuit (remove `R3`). If non-inverting gain > inverting gain + 1, use my final circuit (remove `R5` and `R6`).  If non-inverting gain == inverting gain + 1, you need only `R1` and `R2`.